Deploying program errors out with `Error: 184 write transactions failed`
I'm trying to deploy a solana program on devnet but it's erroring out with the message below.
*[main][~/Documents/crew/marketplace-contracts/target/deploy]$ solana program deploy soundwork_bid.so --with-compute-unit-price 1
=======================================================================
Recover the intermediate account's ephemeral keypair file with
`solana-keygen recover` and the following 12-word seed phrase:
=======================================================================
level middle yard width feed luggage into cable
=======================================================================
To resume a deploy, pass the recovered keypair as the
[BUFFER_SIGNER] to `solana program deploy` or `solana program write-buffer'.
Or to recover the account's lamports, pass it as the
[BUFFER_ACCOUNT_ADDRESS] argument to `solana program close`.
=======================================================================
Error: 273 write transactions failed

environment

solana-cli 1.18.21 (src:0df68a97; feat:4215500110, client:Agave)

anchor-cli 0.29.


Cargo.toml

[dependencies]
anchor-lang = "0.29.0"
anchor-spl = "0.29.0"
mpl-core = "0.7.2"
solana-security-txt = "1.1.1"
soundwork-create = { path = "../soundwork-create", features = ["cpi"] }
soundwork-list = { path = "../soundwork-list", features = ["cpi"] }

solutions tried

using priority fees for the deployment, went as high as 10000000 but it still failed

using a custom RPC endpoint with Helius API, still failed



Downgraded to 1.18.8 and it's working again
solana-install init 1.18.8 


builds without an error but then you have to deal with maxing out on the stack frame
